# How do I replace part of this string with a .* type of regex in php?

Tags: php, regex, web-scraping, explode

I am using explode to manipulate information I am scraping from a website. I am trying to eliminate something specific from the string so that it will return what I want and also add the rest of the items to the array.

```
$pageArray = explode('<td class="player-label"><a href="/nfl/players/antonio-brown.php?type=overall&week=draft">', $fantasyPros);
```

I would like to skip the antonio-brown section and use a regular expression or whatever is best to replace it so that it will not look for a specific name but every name on the list and add them to my array. Do you have any suggestions on what I should use here? I appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Seems looking for `preg_split`

Comment: Looks like a good use for [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to parse the entire page instead of hacking it around using explode and whatever else you are doing. This is what it was made for, working with HTML, and it includes most of the methods available when working with the DOM in JS like `getElementById`, `getElementsByTagName` and methods for checking attributes, values and modifying the dom.

Comment: I was able to get it to show up correctly for one value of the array using substr '$players2 = $secondpageArray[2];

$players2 = substr($players2,106,-100);' I cannot figure out how to use substr with the array and another problem is that the first number could be between 105-107. If I could figure out how to use it with an array and implement and if statement along the lines of if length to first value of substr = certain length then substr($players2,106,-100) elseif substr($players2,107,-100) etc I think that would work. Does anyone know how I could do this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a parser job to me with appropriate `xpath` functions, e.g. `not()`.
Consider the following code:

```
<?php

$data = <<<DATA
<td class="player-label">
    <a href="/nfl/players/antonio-brown.php?type=overall&week=draft">Some brown link here</a>
    <a href="/nfl/players/antonio-green.php?type=overall&week=draft">Some green link here</a>
</td>
DATA;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($data);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$green_links = $xpath->query("//a[not(contains(@href, 'antonio-brown'))]");
foreach ($green_links as $link) {
    // do sth. useful here
}
?>
```

This prints out every link where there's no `antonio-brown` in it.
You can easily adjust this to `td` or any other element.